# Change values in string under condition

Tags: string-manipulation, html

#### how to change the width and height in the `HTML` code into some other values decided by ratio and a fixed width?

The background is that you can adjust a image in your web-page to fit the fixed-width.

---

```
string="<img src=\"/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\Help_1.gif\" alt=\"Help_1.gif\" width=\"882\" height=\"382\" style=\"vertical-align:middle\" /><img src=\"/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\spikeyIcon.png\" alt=\"Spikey\" width=\"20\" height=\"21\" style=\"padding-right:2px; border:0px solid white; vertical-align:middle;\" />";
```

Here is my tries, a snippet of my terrible codes.

I want to change the $\text{width}>800$ into $800$, here it is $882$. `And` height becomes the corresponding value.

```
StringCases[string,(*strT:*) imgTag : Shortest["<img" ~~ __ ~~ ">"] :>   StringReplace[imgTag,    widthString :        Shortest["width=\"" ~~ width__ ~~ "\" "] ~~ (heightSring :         Shortest["height=\"" ~~ height__ ~~ "\" s"(*Here,          there is a strange thing I felt, try delete the 's'.*)]) ~~       pp__ /; (heightE =         ToExpression[         ToExpression[(ttt =             StringDrop[StringDrop[heightSring, 7], -1])]];        widthE =         ToExpression[         ToExpression[(tt = StringDrop[widthString, 6])]]) > 800 :>     "width=\"800\" height=\"" <> ToString[N[800 heightE/widthE]] <>      "\" " <> pp]]

(*
    {<img src="/HTMLFiles\Help\Help\Help_1.gif" alt="Help_1.gif" width="800" height="346.485" 
tyle="vertical-align:middle" />,<img src="/HTMLFiles\Help\Help\spikeyIcon.png" alt="Spikey
" width="20" height="21" style="padding-right:2px; border:0px solid white; vertical-align:
middle;" />}
*)
```

The value of `ttt` is

```
ttt

(*
    "21" 
*)
```

It's Ok, but there is a problem, see the comment of the above code.

#### question1:

---

in the `heightString` pattern, delete the "s" of "style"(I think/hope "\" " is enough to work well like that in `widthString`, but why it dosn't work well?)

```
StringCases[string,(*strT:*) imgTag : Shortest["<img" ~~ __ ~~ ">"] :>   StringReplace[imgTag,    widthString :        Shortest["width=\"" ~~ width__ ~~ "\" "] ~~ (heightSring :         Shortest["height=\"" ~~ height__ ~~ "\" "]) ~~       pp__ /; (heightE =         ToExpression[         ToExpression[(ttt =             StringDrop[StringDrop[heightSring, 7], -1])]];        widthE =         ToExpression[         ToExpression[(tt = StringDrop[widthString, 6])]]) > 800 :>     "width=\"800\" height=\"" <> ToString[N[800 heightE/widthE]] <>      "\" " <> pp]]

(*
    {<img src="/HTMLFiles\Help\Help\Help_1.gif" alt="Help_1.gif" width="800" height="346.485" 
style="vertical-align:middle" />,<img src="/HTMLFiles\Help\Help\spikeyIcon.png" alt="Spike
y" width="20" height="21" style="padding-right:2px; border:0px solid white; vertical-align
:middle;" />}
*)

ttt

(*
    "21" style="padding-right:2px; border:0px solid white; vertical-align:middle;"
*)
```

### question2

---

of course, my codes are urgly, as you see, too many `ToExpression`,and `StringDrop`.

I definitely know you can think up a simpler method? how to optimize my codes?

Welcome to comment, if you're interested with the question and feel hard to understand and badly I'm always poor at expressing.

[here is my page in GitHub with code formatted better](http://hypergroups.github.io/mathematica.se/2013/09/09/A-Problem-Of-StringReplace-Html-width-height/)

One problem need under consideration is the spaces, and that in my method it's sensitive, for example: maybe not all `style`s are after `width=\"20\" height=\"21\" [other...?]style=\"padding...` .

---

@ssch's answer is good, but I wanna see some `StringManipulation` answers, since I'm learning `StringManipulation` via this example. Welcome to post your answers.

Comment: I like that you added a link to your GitHub page. The string posted there works, the one above contains for example \s which Mathematica does not recognize.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I found there is a problem of my `string`, seems not the same as that in my notebook, I hope you've understand my question, that's the most important.

Comment: `"\" s"` is not a good pattern, since sometimes style is not just after `height=\"30\" (other) style=...`.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom thanks, I think now the `string` in SE it's OK, But the code in GitHub, there is a problem of word-wrap, `width=\" 882\" height=\" 382\" 
style=` style is in the new line, that is not intended(in solving).

Comment: HyperGroups, I hope I have more time to look at it later :). (temporary message)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom take your time, not a urge task. I think I fixed the code in Github page also.

Comment: Why do you always keep adding a big, bold title in the body of the question?

Comment: @rm-rf maybe there is a little difference with the title, because I copy the title from Notebook and manually type the title(sometimes). I've made it smaller and thinner now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure it's good to avoid trying to parse the String manually when we can have Mathematica turn it into an [`XMLObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/XMLObject.html) for us with `ImportString[string, {"HTML","XMLObject"}]` which lends itself to more reliable parsing. It's not really simpler but should give less headaches down the line.

Here is a quick demonstration, `modifyXMLAttributes` takes an [`XMLElement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/XMLElement.html) and a rule. The elements (xml)attributes are put in a head with `Attributes` [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orderless.html) before the rule is applied for easier specification of rules.

```
Attributes[OrderlessList] = {Orderless};

modifyXMLAttributes[
  XMLElement[type_, List[oattr___], data___],
  orule_
  ] :=
 Module[{
   attr = OrderlessList[oattr],
   (* This part needs some tuning to be robust
      note that r_ matches Condition below and not RuleDelayed *)
   rule = orule /. r_[List[lhs___], rhs_] :> r[OrderlessList[lhs], rhs]
   },
  XMLElement[type, attr /. rule /. OrderlessList -> List, data]
  ]

xmlobj = ImportString[string, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}];
xmlobj /. img : XMLElement["img", ___] :>
  modifyXMLAttributes[img,
    {"width" -> w_, "height" -> h_, rest___} /; ToExpression[w] > 800 :>
    {"width" -> "800", 
     "height" -> ToString@Round[ToExpression[h]/(800./ToExpression[w])], 
     rest}];
ExportString[%, "XML"]
```

Gives:

```
"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<html version='-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
 <body>
  <img width='800'
      height='346'
      alt='Help_1.gif'
      src='/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\Help_1.gif'
      style='vertical-align:middle' />
  <img alt='Spikey'
      height='21'
      src='/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\spikeyIcon.png'
      style='padding-right:2px; border:0px  solid white; \
vertical-align:middle;'
      width='20' />
 </body>
</html>"
```

Comment: yes, this is a good way, I'll use it if I have more time to develop my html package. :) Now one guideline of mine is to practice String Manipulation, so I use StringExpression as much as possible. Feel free to play with String whenever your time seems ripe if you are interested.